# links inside svg not working on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, svg, href, xlink

I have an inline SVG inside which I have links to other divs.

On desktop and android mobile devices everything works fine whereas on iPad and iPhone it doesn't.

When I tap on the link it flashes as if it has recognised that it is a link but no action takes place.

My SVG is a map with 15 icons on it and is very very long so there's a greatly simplified

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tm1jzcu5/)

Or CSS and HTML below

```css
  #link {
    margin-top: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<svg id="mapImage" version="1.1" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <clipPath id="p.0">
    <path d="m0 0l960.0 0l0 720.0l-960.0 0l0 -720.0z" clip-rule="nonzero"></path>
  </clipPath>
  <g clip-path="url(#p.0)">
    <path fill="#cfe2f3" d="m56.047245 81.91601l143.3386 0l0 129.35434l-143.3386 0z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    <a xlink:href="#link">
      <path fill="#0000ff" d="m102.396324 123.95276l45.25985 0l0 36.629913l-45.25985 0z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>

<div id="link">Linked div</div>
```

Links to external websites embedded in the SVG work fine on iOS as do normal HTML a href links to both external websites and other divs.

Can I edit the inline SVG so that the links work on iOS?  If not would javascript be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or not be the right way to do things but it works.

I removed xlink:href="#" from the anchor tag, gave each one an id then used really simple jquery to open the hidden div.

I have a feeling this breaks rules somewhere but it's the best I can come up with at the moment.  Other advice and opinions are welcome.

HTML, CSS, jQuery below:

```js
  $('#linkTo').click(function() {
    $("#hiddenDiv").toggle();
  });
```

```css
     #hiddenDiv {
       display: none;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       background: red;
     }
     .link {
       cursor: pointer;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mapImage" version="1.1" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <clipPath id="p.0">
    <path d="m0 0l960.0 0l0 720.0l-960.0 0l0 -720.0z" clip-rule="nonzero"></path>
  </clipPath>
  <g clip-path="url(#p.0)">
    <path fill="#cfe2f3" d="m56.047245 81.91601l143.3386 0l0 129.35434l-143.3386 0z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    <a id="linkTo" class="link">
      <path fill="#0000ff" d="m102.396324 123.95276l45.25985 0l0 36.629913l-45.25985 0z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>

<div id="hiddenDiv">
</div>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://%22https://jsfiddle.net/fqqmqnm7/)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; The answer is to attach a click event, setting location.href to the element. in IOS it seems anchors don't work.